# Dynamically change Jquery UI sortable helper?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I trying to set a Jquery UI sortable helper dynamically depending on the area where the mouse is while dragging. In order to do that I'm using the Jquery UI sortable setter. It's changing it for sure, but it's not live (not in the current event). Any ideas how can I make this work?

I've set up an example - http://jsfiddle.net/aJEfp/1/

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to trigger something when it's dropped?

Comment: Yes, if dropped onto the droppable area an event is triggered and a function is called giving the element as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt Sortable was designed to allow the helper element to be changed mid-drag.

I suggest setting the helper to `'clone'` or a custom DOM element, then modifying that element mid-drag, e.g. through `ui.helper` within Sortable event handlers.

Comment: I already forgot about this question and found out myself already, but in the end i did it exact like you answered, so it is correct and hereby you get the bounty. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `$('.content1')` in your event handlers instead of the current sortable `$(this)` that is raising the event.

Here is a fixed version of your jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rkc7e/2/

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I'll correct that code as I ended up using the custom DOM element tactic before I even got an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could target .ui-sortable-helper, as that's the class that is applied while dragging.

```
#sortable .ui-sortable-helper {
    border-color: #FECA40;
    border-width: thick;
}
```